# SmartGWT: Open window from selected record in Listgrid

Tags: java, event-handling, smartgwt

I'm new to `SmartGWT` and I need to open an another window when I select a particular record in a List Grid. Previously I used the `HoverCustomizer` but I cannot move with that further because there are hundreds of records to show. So how can I do this task?

Answer (score 1):

```
ListGrid list = new ListGrid();
//list configuration goes here
list.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
        //Get the clicked record
        Record row = list.getSelectedRecord();

        //Check if thats the record you want
        if(row != null && row.getAttribute("attribute").equals("thingToCheck"){            
            //Now just open the window
            Window window = new Window();
            //Configure here the window
            window.show();
        }
    }
});
```